# constructor injection in regular CLASS LIBRARY with ninject

Tags: ninject, class-library

I have a DotNet class library project (not MVC WebAPI project) that I'd like to use constructor injection with NInject.  I installed the package (v3.2.0.0 runtime v4.0.30319) from Nugget and bind each interface to its respective solid class. These context are pointing to 3 schema in a SQL database.  However, this dependency resolution never took place.  If the contexts are initiated with new(), then the library works.  Thanks for your help.

```js
  public class SomeRepositoryClass : ISomeInterfaceAsync
  {
    private IDBSchema1Context _schema1Ctx; //= new DBSchema1();

    private IDBSchema2Context _schema2Ctx; //= new DBSchema2();

    private IDBSchema3Context _schema3Ctx; //= new DBSchema3();

    private IModelFactory _appModelFactory; //= new ModelFactory();

   public SomeRepositoryClass (
     IDBSchema1Context DBSchema1, 
     IDBSchema2Context DBSchema2, 
     IDBSchema3Context DBSchema3,
     IModelFactory modelFactory)
    {
      _schema1Ctx = DBSchema1;
      _schema2Ctx = DBSchema2;
      _schema3Ctx = DBSchema3;
      _appModelFactory = modelFactory;
    }
```

```js
  public class Bindings : NinjectModule
  {
    public override void Load()
    {
      Bind<IDBSchema1Context>().To<DBSchema1>();
      Bind<IDBSchema2Context>().To<DBSchema2>();
      Bind<IDBSchemaC3ontext>().To<DBSchema3>();
      Bind<IModelFactory>().To<ModelFactory>();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you load your module into a kernel? https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel#the-kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I don't even need the NInject in the class library project, even the constructor injection uses interfaces.  The WebAPI which calls into the class library needs the NInject and Ninject.Web.WebApi packages from Nuget.